# Extract specific strings from a single long line

Tags: python, text-parsing

I'm trying to extract the ID from some network interfaces from a single long line containing several ID's.
I already tried to use split without success. I will appreciate any help

This is a sample of the input, remember this is on a single line of text.

`"Authentication success on Interface Gi1/0/20 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX, Authentication success on Interface Gi1/0/24 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX, Authentication not succeed on Interface Fi1/0/10 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX"`

I expecting output just
Gi1/0/20
Gi1/0/24
Fi1/0/10

Comment: It's pretty trivial to extract these patterns, but for the solution to be sufficiently general, it's helpful if you mention what characteristics define the pattern you're looking to extract. Is it the three-part upper alpha, lower alpha, digit, slash, digit, slash, digit, digit pattern? Will that field change to something else? Is it the fact that the string comes after "Interface" and before "AuditSessionID"? More clarification would be helpful to avoid presumptuous answers.

Comment: If you feel an answer here has solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark next to it. Otherwise, please add a comment, or edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex is suited for this task:

```py
import re

text = 'Authentication success on Interface Gi1/0/20 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX, Authentication success on Interface Gi1/0/24 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX, Authentication not succeed on Interface Fi1/0/10 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX'
re.findall('Interface (.*?) ', text)
```

The `re.findall()` will return a list containing what you wanted.

```py
['Gi1/0/20', 'Gi1/0/24', 'Fi1/0/10']
```

The pattern `'Interface (.*?) '` works by matching Everything beginning with the word "Interface", followed by a space, then something or nothing, then another space. That aforementioned something or nothing is represented by `(.*?)`, which captures (i.e. it gets added to the output of `re.findall()`) whatever is matched by `.*?`, which is any character (`.`), any number of times (`*`), as few times as necessary to match (`?`). You can play around with regexes on sites like https://regex101.com/, which will allow you to run Python regexes, as well as explain them (better than I can).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what properties define the pattern you want to extract, but here's a strict regex that matches an uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter, a digit, a slash, another digit, then a slash and two digits. You might easily extend this to include repetitions and other characters, should they exist in the input string.

```
import re

s = "Authentication success on Interface Gi1/0/20 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX, Authentication success on Interface Gi1/0/24 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX, Authentication not succeed on Interface Fi1/0/10 AuditSessionID 0000000XXXXXXXXXX"

print(re.findall(r"[A-Z][a-z]\d/\d/\d\d", s))
```

Output:

```
['Gi1/0/20', 'Gi1/0/24', 'Fi1/0/10']
```